# C# Ternary operator on WinForms Checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, conditional-operator

I'm trying to change the text of the label based on whether or not a checkbox is checked? Any idea what is wrong in the Ternary operator here? This works if I use 'if else'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOLvZ.png)

```
private void chkBxCompress_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string encAndCom = "Encrypted and Compressed String";
    string encOnly = "Encrypted String";

    chkBxCompress.Checked ? outputLabelEnc.Text = encAndCom : outputLabelEnc.Text = encOnly;
     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
outputLabelEnc.Text = chBxCompress.Checked ? encAndCom : encOnly;
```